# how to change character / to = in route in Angular 7 routing?

Tags: angular, routes

Below is my current route
http://localhost:4200/layout/project/manage-projects/project/project-views/card

i would like to change it to 
http://localhost:4200/layout/project/manage-projects/project/project-views=card

i want to replace last / character to = . please let me know if anyone have solution.

Comment: Do you just need the string to be replaced? Or are we working on a "router" level here?

Comment: working on a router level only. there is list, card, grid views for project-views component so  i would like to display /project-view= list

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to pass values in URL because you cannot change the routing as '='

Comment: i am not passing values , we have different types of views for project-view component like  card, list, grid. so that i need to change to /porject-views=list.

Comment: list, card, grid are the child components for the project-views

Comment: For child routing you should make a individual routing.ts for your project-view component and define routes for your child components. you can check this [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-course-child-routes/)

Comment: i know how to do routing but i would like to replace / which is by default

Comment: I am still not getting the point that why you have to replace that. Please add some example or screenshot to make your point clear